# Is there a more appropriate way to set the language_in option for the closure compiler ( Play 2.1 )?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I had to configure the language_in option in the closure compiler to ECMASCRIPT5 to compile the libs Ember, Angular and others it's require ES5... There must be a better way, but I implemented this way:

```
  // Build.scala

  val root = new java.io.File(".")
  val defaultOptions = new CompilerOptions()
  defaultOptions.closurePass = true
  defaultOptions.setProcessCommonJSModules(true)
  defaultOptions.setCommonJSModulePathPrefix(root.getCanonicalPath + "/app/assets/javascripts/")
  defaultOptions.setLanguageIn(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5)

  CompilationLevel.WHITESPACE_ONLY.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(defaultOptions)

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    (Seq(requireJs += "main.js", requireJsShim += "main.js") ++ closureCompilerSettings(defaultOptions)): _*
  )
```

Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: By chance do you know if this compiler can be disabled with Play2?

Comment: Hello Sebastien, yes it is possible. See: [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/RequireJS-support). But I want to use the benefits of the compiler, but with ECMASCRIPT5.