# Compilation error caused by trailing commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework

edit: I didn't make it clear. I'm using play framework.

I have compilation error as follows: 
"Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option."

But I can't find such an option to change language options. How can I get rid of this compilation error?

I can't modify js file - it is generated and is huge. Also, I really don't care about IE8 and below.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: If you want the code to work in older versions of Internet Explorer, your **only** option is to fix it by removing the stray commas. Even in IE9+, the semantics of trailing commas in array literals is different from that in other browsers.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "compilation error"? Are you using some sort of code compressor?  If so, you'll have to find a way to tell it to ignore such errors if you really don't care about IE7 and IE8.  (It will make a difference in IE9+, like I wrote above, though it's not a syntax error.)

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915444/is-there-a-more-appropriate-way-to-set-the-language-in-option-for-the-closure-co

Comment: I think that correct solution to this problem is... removing triling commas from JS anyway, they are not a part of valid API's and should be avoided

Comment: As I told, script is huge and is subject to change quite often. I tried to delete commas with some tool but it didnt work. I just want play not to care about it but he insists.